# How to access non static property from static function in typescript

Tags: properties, static, typescript

I am mocking the `User` and need to implement static method `findOne` which is static so I do not need to extensiate `User` in my calling class:

```
export class User implements IUser {

    constructor(public name: string, public password: string) { 

        this.name = 'n';
        this.password = 'p';
    }

    static findOne(login: any, next:Function) {

        if(this.name === login.name) //this points to function not to user

        //code

        return this; //this points to function not to user
    }
}
```

But I can't access `this` from static function `findOne` is there a ways of doning it in typescript?

Comment: Generally speaking you can't access `this` from a static function. Static functions are called from the class scope, whereas member functions are called from object scope.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not possible. You can't get an instance property from a static method because there is only one static object and an unknown number of instance objects.

You can, however, access static members from an instance. This will probably be useful for you:

```
export class User {
    // 1. create a static property to hold the instances
    private static users: User[] = [];

    constructor(public name: string, public password: string) { 
        // 2. store the instances on the static property
        User.users.push(this);
    }

    static findOne(name: string) {
        // 3. find the instance with the name you're searching for
        let users = this.users.filter(u => u.name === name);
        return users.length > 0 ? users[0] : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
export class test
{
 private static t:test;
 private name:string;
 constructor()
 {
   t=this;
 }

public static sample()
{
   return t.name;
}
}
```