# How to pass HOC props to getInitialProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In `_app.js`, I wrapped my `MyApp` with a HOC (Higer Order Component) that fetches the status of an user.

```
import AuthHoC from '../utils';
import App from 'next/app';

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, isAuthenticated, idToken } = this.props;

    return (
      <Component 
        {...pageProps} 
        isAuth={isAuthenticated} // Given by AuthHOC
        idToken={idToken}        // Given by AuthHOC
      />
    );
  }
}

export default AuthHoC(MyApp);
```

In my page, I'd like to fetch the status through `getInitialProps`.

```
class Page extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>...</Layout>
        );
    }
}

Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
    console.log('How can I access this -> isAuthenticated'); 
    // if user is not auth, redirect or pass.
    return {}
};

export default Page;
```

How can I fetch `isAuthenticated` in `Page.getInitialProps` ?

Of course I can use `ComponentDidMount()` to redirect based on the users' status, but there's a slight loading time, where they can see the page before `Router.push('/')` triggers. That's why I thought it'd be more appropriate to use `getInitialProps` instead.

Comment: Why is `getInitialProps` not inside the class?

Comment: @JosephD. It can be inside too using `static async getInitialProps(ctx) {...}`, doesn't change much on the issue, I just separated it for readability.

Comment: how can you access `this` inside a static method ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I know I cannot, I'm searching for a way to access `isAuthenticated`. That's why I opened this post.

Comment: @JosephD. That's what I would like to know, in order access in `ctx` I need to define it somehow.

Comment: @JosephD. How would you like me to update it ? What's missing ?

Comment: @HiroyukiNuri please update the code showing `Page` component being rendered and what props were passed.

Comment: It is already there, `_app.js`, this is the only place I have control over `Page`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to access instance properties from a static method. 
See: [How to access non static property from static function in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353393/how-to-access-non-static-property-from-static-function-in-typescript)

Despite it being typescript, the same rules apply.

Comment: If what you say is correct, then my only bet would be to use cookies right?

Comment: What is your current auth strategy? I mean, it looks like your HOC is already passing in isAuthenticated, so you could potentially memoize your components and pass isAuthenticated through context to access it in your apps children.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking about, if I keep it in cookies or local storage I could access it via context.

Comment: After some thinking, I don't need to redirect, I can simply pass a prop to the `Layout` and show a forbidden message there instead.