# Access angular global variables within a static member function (in a service)

Tags: angular, typescript

My code looks like this

```
export class AddressingService {
   myVar;
   protected static getUserId() {
      this.myVar // property myVar doesn't exist on type 'typeof MyService'
   }
}
```

How can I fix that

Comment: Not possible, unless you declare the property as static, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35353493/681929)

Comment: As @nobalG said. Now, it seems like there is some flaw in this design. The method is static but the property no, so does this property hold any state? If you give us more context maybe we can help you better.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861092/static-methods-and-angular-2-services-in-javascript-es6

Answer (score 0):

`myVar` is in scope of the class, therefore it requires an instance of your class to access it.

You can set your variable to be static like so.

```
export class AddressingService {
   static myVar;
   protected static getUserId() {
      this.myVar // property myVar doesn't exist on type 'typeof MyService'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to:

```
export class AddressingService {
   myVar;

   getUserId() {
      this.myVar;
   }
}

// Outside of the class you can access it by:
const serviceInstance = new AddressingService();
serviceInstance.getUserId();
```